Are there standard forms for non-additive quantum codes?
Stabilizer codes have a well known   standard form  for the stabilizers, logicals and destabilizers.
Are there any counterparts for non-additive codes?
In particular I'd like to get a standard form for the this  ((7,2,3)) non additive code (including its logicals...).
As a side, are there standard forms for the  transversal group   of a given code?

If you impose some structure, you can get some type of standard form for things like codeword stabilized codes, which I think of as non-additive codes "lite".
But at their heart, "quantum codes" are just subspaces. So in the most general case, we're asking for "standard forms" for subspaces. Unless someone has a way they really like thinking about subspaces, I think the answer would be "not really".

Thanks for the reference. I don't know if there's a way to check if a non-additive code is codeword stabilized or not; in particular the $((7,2,3))$ code in the question body. The more I look into non-additive codes the less motivated I get in pursuing them...they're just too hard to work with on a number of levels!

@unknown The ((7,2,3)) code is not codeword stabilized because it cannot be written in a basis with only $\pm 1$ coefficients (up to a global normalization scalar). Another way to see it is that all permutation invariant stabilizer codes have $d \leq 2$ (see theorem 3.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12735). It is true that non-additive codes have almost no framework (so far), but my perspective is that that is even more of a reason to study them (although I understand why most people dissent from that viewpoint)!

@unknown Also check out section IV of https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06285 for a procedure for correcting permutation invariant codes.

@EricKubischta I didn't find that section easy to follow. The paper is short on examples : they give one code example but that has 483 qubits!. It would have been easier to understand what they're doing if they picked a small example and walked it all the way through the encoding/decoding process. By any chance did you apply what they did on any of the codes in your paper?

@unknown Yeah it's definitely not super clear and I haven't actually tried to apply it to any of the non-additive codes I have found (I just know that it exists and I have understood enough of it to believe it should work). We are currently working towards a non-additive decoding scheme - basically you can just measure the projectors onto each of the "error spaces" and then undo errors with a reasonable unitary (but the problem is that this won't be fault tolerant because the projectors aren't transversal).
